# What are some tkdiff shortcuts?

Tags: bash, diff, shortcut

I've discovered that 'n' will take you to the next diff, and 'p' to the previous one, and 'enter' to the nearest one.  Any others?

Comment: From the man page : Online help is available by hitting the "help" button.

Comment: hmmm... I have no man page... but I didn't notice the help button! lol

Comment: `diff` is a programmer's tool. Why was this closed as off-topic?

Answer (score 3):

From the help button:

Keyboard Navigation

When a text widget has the focus, you may use the following shortcut keys:

```
f   First diff
c   Center current diff
l   Last diff
n   Next diff
p   Previous diff
1   Merge Choice 1
2   Merge Choice 2
```

The cursor, Home, End, PageUp and PageDown keys work as expected, adjusting  the view in whichever text window has the focus. Note that if  Synchronize Scrollbars is set in Preferences, both windows will scroll at the same time.